# Which in memory database should i choose?

Tags: c#, database, in-memory-database

I have a very big database, around 2000+ tables and each tables has more than 1 million entries. Roughly estimated, this database should be over 10G. My goal is to migrate all entries into in memory database where i can accelerate my analysis greatly.
Also this in memory database should be free to use - i have no budget for it.

Here is a list on available in memory database and which one should i choose, based on your experience? Windows based and c# friendly is preferred. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database#Products

Thanks.

Comment: 10G isn't very big. If you have enough RAM to store your DB in memory, have you benchmarked your queries on your traditional database when you give it enough cache to cache everything?

Comment: No benchmark yet, actually the data is not in database, they are spread in excel format and txt format and i will put effort to organize them.

Answer (score 1):

I have already recommended H2 in a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922340/embedded-pure-java-database-for-clojure/6922609#6922609) for a different language.

There is a [C# mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#microsoft_dot_net) for it.

Comment: thanks, i falsely estimated my database size, the correct size should be 100G to 1000G. H2 is OK for such size? And how about failure over of H2? I mean if i lost my data or data is inconsistent, that would be  very time cost for me to recover.

Comment: Hum, 10G in memory is okay, but since you obviously need at least the same amount of RAM as your database, you would need 1000G of RAM. You have that configuration available ? Otherwise you have to store some data onto disk.

Comment: Thanks, i will load a fraction of data and to have a test.